# Creating drop down box / combo box of bookmarks from ArcGIS Online webmap?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, bookmarks

Without using the clunky ArcGIS bookmark dijit, how do I create a drop down box of bookmarks from an ArcGIS Online webmap (or JSON) that zoom to the extents when clicked?

```
//FYI, JSON format
"bookmarks": [
    {
      "extent": {
        "spatialReference": {"wkid": 102100},
        "xmax": -1.2251063434141435E7,
        "xmin": -1.2561092020865962E7,
        "ymax": 4977986.7113767695,
        "ymin": 4811659.737828305
      },
      "name": "Utah County"
    },
    {
      "extent": {
        "spatialReference": {"wkid": 102100},
        "xmax": -1.2615515185004937E7,
        "xmin": -1.3235572358454255E7,
        "ymax": 4310538.580390846,
        "ymin": 3977884.633293776
      },
      "name": "San Bernardino County"
    }
]
```

Comment: awesomo, Is this a public website? I'd love to see how it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part was needing to reset the selectedIndex on each change event of the html SELECT element so that you can repeatedly hit the same bookmark and the map keeps going back to the extent. Apologize for the mixed dojo and jquery.

```
<!-- html for bookmark combo box, drop down box -->
<select id="comboboxBookmarks">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">Bookmarks...</option>
</select>

dojo.require("esri.arcgis.utils");

//getting the webmap from the query string of URL
var urlObject = esri.urlToObject(document.location.href);
if (urlObject.query.webmap) {
    setAGOLWebMap(urlObject.query.webmap);
}
else {
    //error
}

function setAGOLWebMap(webMapID) {
    esri.arcgis.utils.createMap(webMapID, "map", {
        mapOptions: {
            slider: true,
            logo: false,
            "fadeOnZoom": true,
            "force3DTransforms": true,
            "navigationMode": "css-transforms"
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        map = response.map;

        //Populate Bookmarks
        bookMarks = response.itemInfo.itemData.bookmarks;
        dojo.forEach(response.itemInfo.itemData.bookmarks, function (bookmark, i) {
            $("#comboboxBookmarks").append($("<option>", {
                value: i,
                text: bookmark.name
            }));
        });

        //attach to change event - setting the selectedIndex back to 0 each time lets you repeatedly hit the bookmark
        //e.g. hit bookmark, pan, zoom etc, hit it again. If you don't reset, the change event doesn't fire.
        $("#comboboxBookmarks").change(function () {
            if ($("#comboboxBookmarks").attr("value") > -1) {
                var bookmarkExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(bookMarks[$("#comboboxBookmarks").attr("value")].extent);
                map.setExtent(bookmarkExtent);
            }
            this.selectedIndex = 0;
        });
    });
}
```